# Will translation work as options for number_to_percentage helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these 2 different translation options for `number_to_percentage`:

```
  lt:
    percentage:
      format:
        precision: 2
        delimiter: ''
        format: "%n%"
        strip_insignificant_zeros: false
        separator: '.'
```

and

```
  default:
    percentage:
      format:
        precision: 2
        delimiter: ''
        format: "%n%"
        strip_insignificant_zeros: true
        separator: '.'
```

In case I have LT translations keys I get

```
number_to_percentage 150.000 => 150.00%
```

if I remove LT translations keys:

```
number_to_percentage 150.000 => 150,000%
```

when expected was:

```
150%
```

as I have `strip_insignificant_zeros: true` in translations.
I am understanding wrong how translations works with helpers? Can translations be used as options for a helper?

Thank you.

**application.rb**

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :default
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

Comment: Hey I did not get  percentage of `150`  will be`150%` ???

Comment: @Arv, yea, you didn't get it.. I need to display a number as percentage not to calculate a percentage out of a number.

Comment: I think @rmagnum2002 has issue with default translation

Comment: it means you don't want float right ? then you can use to_i

Comment: have you check this `number_to_percentage(150.000, locale: :default, precision: 0)` ??  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_percentage

Comment: The kind of result @rmagnum2002 is getting is look like Franch Translation.

Comment: I don't want float for a specific translation.. Than means, I shouldn't do any `to_i`, etc.. the translation options should be used as options as it does for anything except `strip_insignificant_zeros`. Adding `to_i` will affect the display of it in all other locales.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this on the .yml file

`format:  %{n}%`

`t(:format, :n => 150.000)`

Comment: Won't this return `150.000%`?

Comment: check this  `t(:format, :n => 150.000.to_i)`, you can pass any value for n

Comment: I appreciate your help, but calling `to_i` to a number that's actually a variable will affect the way this will be displayed in other locales, so in the localization where I need the zeros with precision 2 I'll get them without zeros and that would be wrong.